Sum of pullbacks of SNC divsors again SNC?
Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety (over $\mathbb C$), $\Delta$ an effective SNC (simple normal crossings) divisor on $X$. Consider moreover $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb C}$ and a SNC divisor $a+b$ on $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb C}$ for some different points $a\neq b$. Note that $K_{\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb C}}\sim -a-b$. Finally define $Y:=X\times \mathbb P^1_{\mathbb C}$ with projections $p\colon Y\to X$, $q\colon Y\to \mathbb P^1_{\mathbb C}$.
We have $$K_Y\sim p^*(K_X)-q^*a-q^*b\implies K_Y+q^*a+q^*b\sim p^*K_X\implies K_Y+p^*\Delta+q^*a+q^*b\sim p^*(K_X+\Delta)$$
My quesion is : is $p^*\Delta+q^*a+q^*b$ an SNC divisor ? Since both $p$ and $q$ are smooth, we vave that both $p^*\Delta$ and $q^*a+q^*b$ are SNC divisors since the upllback of an SNC divisor by a smooth morphism is SNC according to this. I am not sure about their sum though. It should be the case but how would you prove it ?

For generality, let $(X, \Delta_X)$ and $(Z, \Delta_Z)$ be log smooth pairs over $\mathbb{C}$, and $p, q: Y := X \times Z \to X, Z$ the respective projections. We claim that $(Y, p^* \Delta_X + q^* \Delta_Z)$ is also log smooth.
To check $p^*\Delta_X + q^*\Delta_Z$ is an snc divisor, we first check normal crossings. Let $(x,z) \in Y$ and fix coordinates $x_1, \dots, x_n$ and $z_1, \dots, z_m$ of $Z$ so that near $x$ and $z$ so that, $$\Delta_X  = \{x_1 \cdots x_{n'} = 0\},\; \Delta_Z = \{z_1 \cdots z_{m'} = 0\}.$$
Then, $p^*x_1, \dots, p^* x_n, q^*z_1, \dots, q^*z_m$ form a system of coordinates and $$p^*\Delta_X + q^*\Delta_Z = \{p^*x_1 \cdots p^* x_{n'} q^*z_1 \cdots q^* z_{m'} = 0\}$$ near $(x,z)$.
On the other hand, the components of $p^*\Delta_X$ and $q^*\Delta_Y$ are the connected components of the preimages of the components of $\Delta_X$ and $\Delta_Y$. Since the components of $\Delta_X$ and $\Delta_Y$ are smooth, as are $p$ and $q$, it follows that the components of $p^*\Delta_X$ and $q^*\Delta_Y$ are smooth as well.
(Definitions: By a log smooth pair $(V, \Delta_V)$ I mean a smooth variety $V$ and a snc effective divisor $\Delta_V$ on $V$. A system of coordinates at $p \in V$ is a minimal set of generators for $\mathfrak{m}_p \subset \mathcal{O}_{V, p}$, or equivalently a lift of a basis of $\mathfrak{m}_p/\mathfrak{m}_p^2$.)
